# count number of ones in a given integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you count the number of ones in a given integer's binary representation.

Say you are given a number `20`, which is `10100` in binary, so number of ones is 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the awesome [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) module.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> binary = bin(20)[2:]
>>> Counter(binary)
Counter({'0': 3, '1': 2})
```

Or you can use the built-in function `count()`:

```
>>> binary = bin(20)[2:]
>>> binary.count('1')
2
```

Or even:

```
>>> sum(1 for i in bin(20)[2:] if i == '1')
2
```

But that last solution is slower than using `count()`

Comment: There is no reason to use `Counter` for this

Comment: Even the guy who made `Counter` didn't use it to solve this ;)

Comment: @jamylak It's still a solution :)

Comment: Yeah but simple is better than complex! Also I wasn't joking before, Raymond Hettinger who contributed the collections module answered this question

Comment: So I’m looking back at this almost five years later, and I’d like to comment that the solution below @Cairnarvon should be used instead of mine. It’s faster, doesn’t depend on any modules, and straightforward

Comment: I like the solution by RaymondHettinger, thats who I was referring to when i said "Even the guy who made Counter didn't use it to solve this" since he actually created Counter

Comment: @jamylak Yep, I don't think 14 year old me understood that at the time :P

Comment: No need to slice off `0b` for counting `1`s.

Comment: `bin()` adds a `-` when input is negative.

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is called the [Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), and there are a lot of algorithms to do it. Here's another straightforward one:

```
def ones(n):
    w = 0
    while (n):
        w += 1
        n &= n - 1
    return w
```

Comment: `a &= b` is equivalent to `a = a & (b)`. `&` is the [bitwise AND operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> num = 20
>>> bin(num)[2:].count('1')
2
```

Comment: The sliciing is unnecessary because the`0b` prefix doesn't contain any ones.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to make this blinding fast is to use lookup tables:

```
table = [bin(i)[2:].count('1') for i in range(256)]

def pop_count(n):
   cnt = 0
   while n > 0:
     cnt += table[n & 255]
     n >>= 8
   return cnt
```

In Python, any solution using `bin` and `list.count` will be faster, but this is nice if you want to write it in assembler.

Comment: If you are using assembly, `n & 255` will be dramatically faster than `n % 256`.

Comment: Your code has a typo, you wrote `n & 256` instead of `n & 255`.

Answer (score 3):

The `int` type has a new method [`int.bit_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) since python 3.10a, returning the number of ones in the binary expansion of a given integer, also known as the population count as follows:

```
n = 20
bin(n)
'0b10100'
```

`n.bit_count()` returns `2` as it has 2 ones in the binary representation.

Answer (score 2):

The [*str.count*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method and [*bin*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) function make short work of this little challenge:

```
>>> def ones(x):
        "Count the number of ones in an integer's binary representation"
        return bin(x).count('1')

>>> ones(20)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using bit shifting `>>` and bitwise and `&` to inspect the least significant bit, like this:

```
def count_ones(x):
    result = 0
    while x > 0:
        result += x & 1
        x = x >> 1
    return result
```

This works by shifting the bits right until the value becomes zero, counting the number of times the least significant bit is 1 along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new coder and I found this one logic simple. Might be easier for newbies to understand.

```
def onesInDecimal(n):
  count = 0
  while(n!=0):
    if (n%2!=0):
        count = count+1
        n = n-1
        n = n/2
    else:
        n = n/2
  return count
```

Answer (score 0):

For a special case when you need to check quickly whether the binary form of the integer `x` has only a single 1 (and thus is a power of 2), you can use this check:

```
if x == -(x | (-x)):
    ...
```

The expression `-(x | (-x))` is the number that you get if you replace all 1s except the last one (the least significant bit) in the binary representation of `x` with 0.

Example:

12 = 1100 in binary

-12 = ...110100 in binary (with an infinite number of leading 1s)

12 | (-12) = ...111100 in binary (with an infinite number of leading 1s)

-(12 | (-12)) = 100 in binary

Comment: This answer is more of a comment/discussion point than an answer. Please consider adding it to the related answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the input number is 'number'

```
number =20
len(bin(number)[2:].replace('0',''))
```

Another solution is

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(list(bin(number))[2:])['1']
```

Comment: Your first solution is like swatting flies with a sledgehammer. You can just use `str.count('1')`. Also no need to convert to a list if you use Counter