# How to calculate hamming weight for many numbers in one file?

Tags: python

I have a file which contains in each line a set  numbers like this:

```
[222   9 217  21  65 197]
[222   9 217  21  65 197]
[222 207 217  21  65 197]
[  9 222 217  21  65 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
........
```

I  want to calculate the hamming weight of each number as a result I want  to have:

```
[6   2 5  3  2 4]
[6   2 5  3  2 4]
[6   6 5  3  2 4]
[2   6 5  3  2 4]
[6   5 3  2  5 4]
[6   5 3  2  5 4]
[6   5  3  2 5 4]
[6   5  3  2 5 3]
........
```

I use this script to calculate  the hamming weight:

```
hw = [bin(x).count("1") for x in range(256)]
print(hw[207])
```

But I can do that for only one number, How could I do that for all the file?

Could help me please?

Comment: You can use nested for loops in list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
from io import StringIO

text = '''[222   9 217  21  65 197]
[222   9 217  21  65 197]
[222 207 217  21  65 197]
[  9 222 217  21  65 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]
[222 117  21  65 217 197]'''


def hw(number):
    ret = 0
    while number != 0:
        ret += number & 1
        number >>= 1
    return ret
    # might be faster:
    # return bin(number).count('1')

# with open(..., 'r') as file
with StringIO(text) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace('[', '')
        line = line.replace(']', '')
        numbers = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
        hws = [hw(n) for n in numbers]
        print(hws)
```

to make it work for you, remove the `text` part above, remove the `with StringIO(text) as file:` line and replace it by the `with open(..., 'r') as file` line. you have to insert your filename there (or better: the full path of your file).

i also supplied a different version of the hamming weight; based on bit-operations.

Comment: It is also possible to extract the numbers using a regex, instead of all `line` manipulations: `numbers = [int(n) for n in re.findall('\d+', line)]` or directly get the `hws` as `hws = [hw(int(n)) for n in re.findall('\d+', line)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loops, and you don't need a list comprehension.

```
def hamAll(seq):
  output = []
  for i in seq:
    output.append(bin(i).count("1"))
  return output
```

*shell:*

```
>>> hamAll([1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  255])
...        #1  10 11  100 101 11111111
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8]
```

Then, if you wanna input a file, i'd use `re` module.

```
import re

def hamAll(seq):
  output = []
  for i in seq:
    output.append(bin(i).count("1"))
  return output

with open("filename.txt", 'r') as file:
  inputf = file.read()

inputf = re.sub(r"[\n\[\]]", " ", inputf)
numbers = inputf.split(" ")
hamReady = []
for i in numbers:
  if i == "":
    continue
  if i.isdecimal():
    hamReady.append(int(i))

print(hamAll(hamReady))
```

*shell:*

```
======== Restart: test.py ========
[6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use the method of calculating the hamming weight as found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15540869/7938752

Use a combination of for loops with some string formatting to take the text from the input file, extract the numbers, calculate the hamming weight, reformat the numbers, then print those numbers and write them to an output file.

Example code:

```
def get_hm(x):
    return bin(x).count("1")

def format_numbers(results):
    count = 0
    result = "["
    for x in results:
        if x >= 100:
            result = result + str(x)
        elif x >= 10:
            result = result + " " + str(x)
        else:
            result = result + "  " + str(x)
        if count < len(results):
            result = result + " "
        count += 1
    result = result + "]"
    return result

def get_numbers(line):
    line = line.replace("[", "").replace("]","").replace("\n","")
    results = []
    for x in line.split(" "):
        if x != "" and x != " ":
            results.append(get_hm((int(x))))
    return format_numbers(results)


f = open("input.txt")
y = f.readlines()
for line in y:
    print get_numbers(line)
f.close()

#optional code that writes the results to a file.
f = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in y:
    f.write(get_numbers(line) + "\n")
f.close()
```